# Reference field in a map of sObjects

Tags: apex, map

I have a map that I need to reference the create date of an sObject that is part of a map. The map is:

```
global Map<String,List<wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c>>   
mapOfContactIdVsEmailTracking = new 
Map<String,List<wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c>>();
```

The debug is of the map is:

```
16:12:38:107 USER_DEBUG [97]|DEBUG|***MapOfContactIdVsEmailTracking*** 
{0031U00000nox8vQAA=(wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c:{Id=a0s1U000000vAi9QAE, 
CreatedDate=2019-09-17 19:56:43, Name=Test, 
wbsendit__Contact__c=0031U00000nox8vQAA, wbsendit__Activity__c=Opened}
```

How can I reference the CreatedDate in the map?

I'm basing an if statement on the last ran date for a batch class so it will only run when created date > the last run date.

Comment: What do you mean by "reference" the Created Date?

Comment: @DavidReed So I can do something similar to:  if (emailTrakingHistory.CreatedDate > LastRun.Last_Run_Batch_Date_Time__c) {

I tried: System.debug(MapOfContactIdVsEmailTracking.values().CreatedDate);
but that just ended in errors

Comment: You have a Map of Lists here. What object are you trying to obtain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there are 2 parts to your question. First is the actual how to part. It seems like you don't really understand the data structures provided by SFDC.

The second is architectural, Your code has me concerned that the architecture behind what you're trying to do is not optimal.

I'm going to focus on the first part. If you have architectural questions, you can ask another question for advice but it may go beyond the scope of this website.

### Lists

A list is an ordered set of object. Lists do not guarantee uniqueness. WOrking with lists looks like the following:

```
List<wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c> activities = ...; what ever you do to populate the list

system.debug(activities[0].createdDate); // this will show you one created date

for (wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c activity : activities ) {
    system.debug(activity.createdDate); // this will loop through all activities and display all created dates
}
```

In your comment you mentioned you were doing `map.values()`. This method returns a list of all of the values in the map. In your case, your values are list objects themselves. Because of this, your data type would be:

```
List<List<wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c>> listOfLists =
     mapOfContactIdVsEmailTracking.values();
```

Working with a list of lists would look like this:

```
List<wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c> firstList = listOfLists[0];
system.debug(firstList[0].createdDate); // will show the created date of the first record in the first list
```

Looping through lists of lists looks like:

```
for (List<wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c> activities : listOfLists) {
    for (wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c activity : activities ) {
        system.debug(firstList[0].createdDate); // will show all created dates of all records in all lists
    }
}
```

### Maps

Maps are un-ordered. The keys are unique and the values are not unique. The purpose of a map is to easily identify an object by a single unique piece of information, in most cases this will be a record Id.

```
Map<String,List<wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c>>
```

This creates a map of lists identified by a string, in your case the contact Id.

In this case, you're probably using a list or map of contacts to pull data from the map. This would look like:

```
List<Contact> contacts = ...; // Some method to identify contacts
List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();

for (Contact contact : contacts) {
    DateTime lastActivityDate = contact.Last_Activity_Date__c;

    for (
        wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c activity : 
        mapOfContactIdVsEmailTracking .get(contact.Id)
    ) {
        if (activity.CreatedDate > lastActivityDate) {
            lastActivityDate = activity.CreatedDate;
        }
    }

    if (contact.Last_Activity_Date__c != lastActivityDate) {
        contact.Last_Activity_Date__c = lastActivityDate;
        contactsToUpdate.add(contact);
    }
}

update contactsToUpdate;
```

### Disclaimer

Keep in mind this answer is strictly to show you how to use maps and lists and is only sort of put into context of your current use case **YOU WILL HAVE TO MODIFY THE CODE IN THIS ANSWER FOR IT TO WORK FOR YOU** I will answer questions about this answer but I will not update it to fit your specific use case, that is your job.

This is also not the most optimal way to perform the task outlined in my answer, the task above would typically be performed by an aggregate query.